Yup ObjectSchema with a TypeScript union type
Say I have two types, BasicUser and AdminUser that are unioned into one type User.
interface UserBase {
  name: string
  authenticationType: AuthenticationType;
}

interface BasicUser extends UserBase {
  authenticationType: 'basicUser';
  privileges: string;
}

interface AdminUser extends UserBase {
  authenticationType: 'adminUser';
}

export type User = BasicUser | AdminUser;

I am trying to build a schema that can validate both a User type whether that was constructed as an AdminUser or BasicUser.
import * as yup from 'yup';
import { AuthenticationType, User } from './types';

const bobAdmin: User = {
  name: 'Bob',
  authenticationType: 'adminUser',
}

const sallyBasicUser: User = {
  name: 'Sally',
  authenticationType: 'basicUser',
  privileges: 'read'
}

// Schema validation fails typecheck
const userSchema: yup.ObjectSchema<User> = yup.object({
  name: yup.string().required(),
  authenticationType: yup.string().oneOf<AuthenticationType>(['basicUser', 'adminUser']).defined().required(),
  privileges: yup.string().when('authenticationType', ([authenticationType], schema) => {
    if(authenticationType === 'basicUser') {
      return schema.required();
    }
    return schema;
  })
});

The validation actually works, but TypeScript is complaining that the schema doesn't satisfy the User type.

I've tried breaking the schemas into two distinct schemas and using mixed().oneOf([]), but that didn't work either.
Are there any workarounds or tips anyone could provide? Thank you.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-fszugq?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Apparently, Yup doesn't support the feature. My workaround was to cast the failing portion of the schema to any... Not ideal.
Zod handles this case nicely using discriminated unions.
const userSchema = z.discriminatedUnion('authenticationType', [
    z.object({ authenticationType: z.literal('adminUser') }).merge(baseUserSchema),
    z.object({ authenticationType: z.literal('basicUser'), privileges: z.string() }).merge(baseUserSchema),
]) satisfies z.ZodType<User>;  // Gives you schema typing against User type


https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-bcbhz1?file=src%2Fmain.ts
